# Getting error halfway, creating different objects from text file

Tags: java

I have a text file which goes like this:

> 1574683 Abyssinia
>   8546279 Royal_Oak
>   2454438 Oceanway
>   9146578 Atilgan
>   3378841 Albatros
>   6562152 Imbat
>
> 1000085321 N N
>   1000255963 N N
>   1000511926 N N
>   1000853210 N N
>   1001279815 N N
>   1001791741 N N
>   1002388988 N N
>   1003071556 N N
>   1003839445 N N
>   ...

This text file represents a port. First 6 lines are 6 ships' IMO numbers and their names. The rest are containers. There are 632 containers. Port is an object and it keeps containers and ships -which are also objects- as two separate object arraylists. Here's my attempt at extract the data from the text file:

```
Scanner inputFileReader = null;
    try {

        inputFileReader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NesneProjesi\\src\\\\liman.txt"));
        String line;
        String[] lineCutter;
        //Gemi yeniGemi = null; //---declare your arraylist-containing object here.
        while (inputFileReader.hasNextLine()){
        line = inputFileReader.nextLine();

        if(line.length() > 7){
            lineCutter = line.split(" ");

            if(lineCutter[0].length()== 7){

            int imo = Integer.valueOf(lineCutter[0]);
            String isim = lineCutter[1];
            Gemi yeniGemi = new Gemi(imo,isim);
            liman.Gemiler.add(yeniGemi);
            }else if(lineCutter[0].length() == 10){

            int ser= Integer.valueOf(lineCutter[0]);
            String Konteyner_Ozelligi= lineCutter[1];
            String Icerik_Ozelligi= lineCutter[2];
            Konteyner yeniKonteyner = new Konteyner(ser,Konteyner_Ozelligi,Icerik_Ozelligi);
            liman.Lkonteynerler.add(yeniKonteyner);
        }

         }
        }

} catch (Exception e) {

    //e.printStackTrace();

} finally {
        //System.out.println(liman.Lkonteynerler);
        inputFileReader.close();
        return liman.Gemiler;
}
```

This code gives this error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2182634381"

That number is on the 172nd line. It doesn't read anything from then on. I have no idea why it works until then and not after. If there's any more information you need, I will provide. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For integer, maximum number is: 2147483648 and minimum number is -2147483648 which 2^31

if you want to enter a number bigger than 2147483648, you should use "long" instead of "int"

Comment: Don't forget that whenever you type a number java thinks it is an int. If you want to make it a long put an "L" behind the number. Eg: long number = 138262921694L;